# Can a GNU screen session have both split and non split workspaces?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

When using GNU screen, if you enter a screen session and then split it into desired layout. Is it possible to also have a full screen shell that you can switch to within the same session? Or once you start splitting does that mean you are constrained to one view and you can only alternate between visible split panes and then switch active shells within those panes?

I often split a screen session to monitor multiple logs or looped command output at the same time but I'd also like a full screen shell to work on as well without having to have a separate screen sessions that I need to detach from split/attach to full screen etc.

If the screen can't do this, can tmux, or similar do it?

Answer (score 1):

GNU screen 4.2 (2014) added [layout](https://gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Layout.html) support for this:

> Layouts will help organize your regions. You can create one layout of four horizontal regions and then create a separate layout of regions in a two by two array. The regions could contain the same windows, but they don’t have to. You can easily switch between layouts and keep them between detachments and reattachments.

The following is my keybindings:

```
bind           y  command -c layout
bind -c layout \' layout select
bind -c layout ?  layout show
bind -c layout c  layout new
bind -c layout d  layout remove
bind -c layout i  layout number
bind -c layout n  layout next
bind -c layout p  layout prev
bind -c layout 0  layout select 0
bind -c layout 1  layout select 1
bind -c layout 2  layout select 2
bind -c layout 3  layout select 3
bind -c layout 4  layout select 4
bind -c layout 5  layout select 5
bind -c layout 6  layout select 6
bind -c layout 7  layout select 7
bind -c layout 8  layout select 8
bind -c layout 9  layout select 9
```

---

And I have something like this in screenrc so it creates a few layouts on startup:

```
#
#  +-------+
#  |       |
#  |   0   |
#  |       |
#  +-------+
#
layout new

screen 0
screen 1
screen 2
screen 3
select 0

#
#  +---+---+
#  |   | 1 |
#  | 0 |---+
#  |   | 2 |
#  +-------+
#
layout new

select 0
split -v
focus right
select 1
split
focus down
select 2
focus left

#
#  +---+---+
#  | 0 | 2 |
#  +---+---+
#  | 1 | 3 |
#  +---+---+
#
layout new

select 0
split -v
split
focus down
select 1
focus right
select 2
split
focus down
select 3
focus top

# Select the layout you prefer
#layout select 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this with screen. The best I could come up with was to have multiple sessions (with different escape characters). The multiple log windows were all in one session, and the other session contains, in one window, screen -r log. Then I could split the log session, and still be able to cycle through the other session windows.

I believe it is possible in tmux, but I have not made the switch (yet).

EDIT: It definitely is possible, and very easy, in tmux. And the switch was very easy (there's a screen-keys.conf file in tmux examples that I started with). This is a script I wrote to create a full screen session with 3 windows, the third has 3 panes in it, one 20% and the other two 40%. It's callable from crontab: @reboot

```
tmux new-session -d -s base /bin/bash
tmuxwin() {
  tmux new-window -t base -n $1 /bin/bash
  sleep 1
  shift
  tmux send "$1" C-m
}
tmuxwin second "echo second" 
# These all end up in one window
tmuxwin thirddotone "echo 3.1"
tmuxwin thirddottwo "echo 3.2"
tmuxwin thirddotthree "echo 3.3"

# join 3.1 to 3.2. Give 3.1 20%
tmux select-window thirddotone
tmux joinp -p 80 -s +
# join 3.3 to 3.2. Even split
tmux joinp -s +
# and fix the names...
tmux rename-window three

# I am waiting for you, Vizzini. You told me to go back to the beginning. 
# So I have. This is where I am, and this is where I’ll stay. I will not be moved.
tmux select-window -t 0
```

So my recommendation is to switch to tmux. I've been using tmux for less than a week and am not looking back.

Answer (score 0):

### Update: screen 4.2 (2014) added layout for this.

9 years later I've come across the same question and the answer is: `screen` can't do this, better switch to `tmux` if you need this feature (as you may have already done!)

A plausible solution for `screen` is: `^a Q` which makes the current windows fullscreen ("only")

Comment: screen 4.2 (2014) added *layout* for this. see https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Layout.html

Comment: @pynexj Good to know. Worth noting it comes without defaults bindings

Comment: ok. i'll post an answer with my keybindings.